# Java: Parsing a string representation into a tree representaiton

Tags: java, string, parsing, tree, representation

I need to use Java, so scripting language support must NOT be used.

The string representation I need to parse is like:

```
op1 (t1,t2,t3,...)
```

where t1, t2, t3 etc. can again be of something like `op2 (t11,t12,t13 ...)` or just an atomic unit (can not be composed of elements in itself)

A concrete example is:

```
op1 (op2 (t1 t2) t3)
```

I want to parse it in a tree like structure (hierarchical)

```
op1
 op2
  t1
  t2
 t3
```

Assuming op1 is the root of the tree, op2 is the left subchild of op1, and t3 is the right subchild of op1. t1 and t2 are the subchildren of op2, respectively.

How can I do it in Java? THe challenging part is that the resulting tree must not be a binary tree. A node can have arbitrary number of children.

Comment: Hey Bob, is this homework?  It would be best if it had the `homework` tag.

Comment: @digitaljoel The `homework` tag has been deprecated.  Check on meta-stack overflow for details if you are interested.  All the same, it is not to be used any longer.

Comment: Interesting @BlackVegetable I hadn't seen that. Thanks for pointing it out. For anyone else interested here's a link to the meta post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @Bob [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) What do you know about string parsing? You mentioned in another comment that you can't use a third-party library, so that means you need to build this from scratch. Explaining everything about how to do that will take more time than most of us here have. Help us help you by asking some specific questions about what you have tried and what problems you have encountered along the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use JavaCC then you could look at the [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) class.  You could do it in a couple passes.  First, tokenize on the parenthesis, creating a first pass tree.  Then you could walk the tree and tokenize on space fleshing out the tree nodes further for those nodes that only have leafs and not nested trees (i.e. have no children that contain parens)

`op1 (op2 (t1 t2) t3)` when tokenized on '(' and ')' would give the tokens (assuming you ask for tokens to be included) `op1, (, op2, (, t1 t2, ), t3, )`  From that you walk through the tokens.  You know your first is the parent.  Second is a paren so you know that you have a complex child. so your tree would be:

```
op1
  op2
```

Then you hit another paren, meaning a new complex child.  The next token after the second open paren is `t1 t2` so your tree is

```
op1
  op2
    t1 t2
```

Then you get a close paren token, so you end the complex child of op2 and your next token is the next child of op1, meaning your tree would then look like

```
op1
  op2
    t1 t2
t3
```

Finally you hit the last close paren, which ends the complex child of op1.

Now you can walk the tree, splitting the child nodes on space.  First node is op1 so no split, same with op2.  't1 t2' splits into 't1', and 't2' so you end up splitting that node into two so your tree looks like

```
op1
  op2
    t1
    t2
  t3
```

You could probably easily put the space splitting into the first method so you wouldn't have to walk the tree twice.

Comment: Can you show me some concrete code for dealing with parenthesis (children) or spaces (members at the same level)? I can then take that and complete. I have trouble of thinking in Java. I used functional programming languages where I would do it in straight recursive functions. My problem is how can I find out the that the children for op1 consist of op2 (t1 t2) and t3? Finding out this breaking position is the only thing I can not solve.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was reading through the StringTokenizer class. Seems like it is very powerful. Neved used this before.

Comment: Question edited with some more information about the algorithm.

Comment: @Bob Java supports recursion. Step back from the computer for a moment and describe in words how you would parse the string. This should help you figure out how to do it in Java (or any other programming language.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this kind of parser is very easy to create with [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/), just create simple grammar (subject for doing some research - check out this [link](http://javacc.java.net/doc/simpleREADME.html))

Comment: The thing is I am not allowed to use any third party library.I need to come up with the native java. can you help me with this?

Comment: javacc will generate Java sources for you, so you only need to add some "meat" to the code.

Comment: Would be good if  I could write those java sources on my own :-) I did write parser for generating binary tree representations. But in this case, the number of children for a node is arbitrary which makes it hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a very quick and very dirty, and provably buggy solution. Hey, at least it solves your example!!!!

```
package parser;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author gpeche
 */
public class Parser {

    private static abstract class Node {
        String name;

        String getName() { return name; }

        abstract boolean isComposite();

        Node(String name) { this.name = name; }        
    }

    private static class PrimitiveNode extends Node { 
        @Override boolean isComposite() { return false; }

        PrimitiveNode(String name) { super(name); }

        @Override public String toString() { return "PrimitiveNode(\"" + name + "\")"; }        
    }

    private static class CompositeNode extends Node { 
        Collection<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

        void addChild(Node childNode) { children.add(childNode); }

        Collection<Node> getChildren() { return new ArrayList<Node>(children); }

        @Override boolean isComposite() { return false; }

        CompositeNode(String name) { super(name); }

        @Override public String toString() { 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("CompositeNode(\"");
            sb.append(name);
            sb.append("\") { ");
            boolean isFirstNode = true;
            for (Node node: children) {
                if (!isFirstNode) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(node.toString());
                isFirstNode = false;                   
            }
            sb.append(" }");
            return sb.toString();
        }        
    }

    // Parser state
    int pos = 0;

    String[] tokens;

    static final String OPENING_PAR = "(";
    static final String CLOSING_PAR = ")";
    static final String OP_PLUS = "+";
    static final String OP_MINUS = "-";
    static final String OP_MULTIPLY = "*";
    static final String OP_DIVIDE = "/";
    static final String OP_MODULUS = "mod";
    static final String OP_INT_DIVIDE = "div";

    static final Collection<String> PARENTHESIS = Arrays.asList(OPENING_PAR, CLOSING_PAR);

    static final Collection<String> OPERATIONS = Arrays.asList( OP_PLUS,
                                                                OP_MINUS,
                                                                OP_MULTIPLY,
                                                                OP_DIVIDE,
                                                                OP_MODULUS,
                                                                OP_INT_DIVIDE);


    public Node parse(String treeRepresentation) {
        tokenize(treeRepresentation);
        return parseNode();
    }

    private void tokenize(String treeRepresentation) {
        treeRepresentation = treeRepresentation.replace("(", " ( ");
        treeRepresentation = treeRepresentation.replace(")", " ) ");
        tokens = treeRepresentation.split("\\s+");
    }

    private Node parseNode() {
        // check that current token is not a "syntax" token
        String currentToken = tokens[pos];
        if (PARENTHESIS.contains(currentToken)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid token %d, expected identifier. got %s", pos + 1, currentToken));
        }

        boolean isComposite = currentToken != null && 
                              (currentToken.startsWith("op") ||  // Accept identifiers as operations (function support :P)
                               OPERATIONS.contains(currentToken));
        return isComposite? parseComposite() : parsePrimitive();
    }

    private Node parseComposite() {
        CompositeNode composite = new CompositeNode(tokens[pos]);
        pos++;                

        if (!OPENING_PAR.equals(tokens[pos])) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid token %d, expected '(', got %s", pos + 1, tokens[pos]));
        } else {
            // Ignore opening parenthesis
            pos++;
        }

        boolean nextIsIdentifier;
        do {
            composite.addChild(parseNode());
            nextIsIdentifier = !PARENTHESIS.contains(tokens[pos]);            
        } while (nextIsIdentifier);

        if (!CLOSING_PAR.equals(tokens[pos])) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid token %d, expected ')', got %s", pos + 1, tokens[pos]));
        } else {
            pos++;
        }

        return composite;
    }

    private Node parsePrimitive() {
        // Create primitive node and advance position
        Node result = new PrimitiveNode(tokens[pos]);
        pos++;
        return result; 
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        Node parsedNode = parser.parse("op1 (op2 (t1 t2) t3)");
        System.out.println(parsedNode.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to split this problem on two sub problems, first - parsing input, second - creating tree.

You could use string tokenizer and stack for the first one, you could skip "op1"s because in general your problem looks like ((t1 t2) t3). So when your current element will be = ")" you should pop elements from your stack until you'll reach "(" and create new Node out of that elements and put it back to stack. Another question is what type of data you'll store in the stack, obviously it wouldn't be strings, so probably you have to create some hierarchy of elements which could be placed there, e.g. StringElement, NodeElement, StartQuoteElement.